# Can't get AJAX request to load more than once in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

I have been messing with this code for quite some time, works in FF, Chrome, Safari but IE for some reason will only load one time.  I have tried using the time function as well as the math.random function in the querystring to make the URL unique.  I used firebug to make sure that my math.random function was working correctly and it seems to be but for some reason IE will only load the page once.  I am about to pull my hair out and abandon the whole idea, please help!!

Code below:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});


var myHandle = setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'randomize2.php?ck=' + Math.random(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // data is ur summary
            $('#dispeople').html(data);
        }
    })
}, 2000);

 var mybutton2 = document.getElementById("mybutton2");
```

upon your suggestion I checked out the IE developer tools and found the code was breaking further down the page in the following code block:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.all').quicksand( $('.warm li'), {
            duration: 1000,
            attribute: 'id',
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: are you sure it's running twice?

Comment: Which IE? There are fairly big differences between IE6, 7, 8, and 9. But I'm not seeing any problems with the quoted code at all. Check for the browser complaining of script errors and such (it can be fairly subtle with IE sometimes -- if you're using IE8 or 9 use the Developer Tools) to see if there's something going wrong *elsewhere*, in code you haven't quoted.

Comment: Same here. I even tried it locally, works fine in IE8. Did you put the code inside jQuery's document.ready?

Comment: I am actually using IE 9, upon your suggestion of using the developer tools I found the code was breaking at the following code block further down the page, I have placed it in the original question

Comment: @tsisson81: Code formatting would help a ***lot***. The bits of code you've posted have been unreadable until people have fixed them for you.

Comment: Sorry thought I was using the correct code formatting described by the forum

Comment: @tsisson81: (Stack Overflow isn't a forum.) But did you *look* at the question as you were typing it? or afterward? Code indentation counts a **lot** for readability, and readability directly translates into fewer errors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand what you are saying now, yes I will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I've formatted the code, an error (perhaps not *the* error) jumps out:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.all').quicksand( $('.warm li'), {
            duration: 1000,
            attribute: 'id',
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    } // <========================= Extra } here
    }, 5000);
});
```

I can't imagine Chrome or the others running that code.

Comment: good catch must have been the remainder of something else I had tried.  I removed it and was still experiencing the same issue in IE. I decided to try and comment out the line e.preventDefault(); as the IE developer tool was saying it was breaking there.  After commenting that out it seems to work in IE but I am fairly new to JQuery so I am not quite sure if this is good practice or not?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this code?

```
// Disable browser cache Ajax.ActionLinks
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

IE6,7 are more sensitive with javascript code's quality, like ';', 'var' missing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor activity.
You can then check if the query strings are actually different.
I suspect ie might be serving the request of its cache.